# WebWorker causing memory usage grows very fast and high

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am using web worker to fetch data in multiple threads but my CPU usage is so high in this code. I meant CPU usage grows very fast and keeps growing !!!

Can anyone help me to see where i am causing memory leakage or not properly monitoring the events?

```
const MAX_WORKERS = 26;
let promises = [];

function createWorker(data1, data2) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let worker = new Worker();
    worker.onmessage = (event) => {
      postMessageRes = event.data;
      // this is do wait if there is any work need to be done before worker start doing its work
      if (postMessageRes == 200) {
        worker.postMessage([
          nodePagesString,
          pagesString,
          copcString,
          data1,
          data2,
          [
            x_min,
            y_min,
            z_min,
            widthx,
            widthy,
            widthz,
            scaleFactor[0],
            scaleFactor[1],
            scaleFactor[2],
          ],
        ]);
      } else {
        workerCount += 1;
        let position = postMessageRes[0];
        let color = postMessageRes[1];
        let localPosition = [];
        let localColor = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < position.length; i++) {
          positions.push(position[i]);
          localPosition.push(position[i]);
          colors.push(color[i]);
          localColor.push(color[i]);
        }
        if (workerCount == MAX_WORKERS) {
          workerCount = 0;
          promises = [];
        }
        worker.terminate();
        resolve([localPosition, localColor, data1]);
      }
    };
  });
}
```

and it is called in code:

```
for (let m = 0; m < keyCountMap.length; ) {
    let remaining = totalNodes - doneCount;
    let numbWorker = Math.min(MAX_WORKERS, remaining);
    for (let i = 0; i < numbWorker; i++) {
      // console.log("i am entering first time");
      promises.push(createWorker(keyCountMap[m], keyCountMap[m + 1]));
      doneCount++;
      m += 2;
      if (doneCount % MAX_WORKERS == 0) {
        await syncThread();
        // console.log(doneCount, "i am done");
      }
    }
  }
  console.log("it finished at", clock.getDelta());
}
```

I have a task where i have to fetch load of data for keyCountMap.length times which is in forloop

My problem here is that when i run the code the CPU memory usage by browser grows so much and so high like 4GB by this project alone.

I am skeptical if i am closing the worker correctly or not.

I believe there is memory leakage in worker, can anyone please help me to make sure i am closing everything properly or anyway i can check it.

This is my network tab

[image]

Comment: Make sure you're declaring all your variables (**all** of them) with `let` or `const`; several in the code you posted are not declared (though they may be declared elsewhere). Also what is the value of `MAX_WORKERS`?

Comment: MAX_WORKERS is 26 and thank you so much for comment !! If i may ask i guess i have all variable locally defined except postMessageRes = event.data; right? I made it       let postMessageRes = event.data; Do you think i am missing something?

Comment: 50 is a lot. Are you running this on a machine with a lot of cores? Have you benchmarked w/ a reasonable number of workers? How much data is being shuffled back and forth?

Comment: I am sorry it's 26

Comment: How much data is being shuffled back and forth? How do you know this or how can i know this?

Comment: I have edited the question with network tab screenshot !!

Comment: Don't spawn more than `navigator.hardwareConcurrency - 1` Workers, that will make them use task switching instead of true parallelism. Then, don't start a worker per task. Create a fixed number of multi-task Workers. Creating a Worker is an heavy operation on itself, a whole JS context + event-loop and loads of other internals need to be created per Worker.

Comment: @pravinpoudel How can you know how much data is being shuffled back and forth? You're the one passing the data back and forth; look at it? 26 is a lot of workers unless you're on a machine w/ many CPUs. Benchmark performance & resource usage with different numbers of workers, e.g., 2, 4, 8, 16 etc. There's tradeoffs to make, but which ones are worth making depends on specifics.